# Performed git pull off master and got merge conflicts

Tags: git

I have a project I would like to create a branch off master. I am new to the project, never worked on it before and yet when I performed a `git pull` to get the latest changes, I immediately got merge conflicts.

Definitely not what I expected considering I have not done any work on this project before.

How do I resolve this?

This is what the `git pull` actually looked like:

```
git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 46, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (46/46), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 46 (delta 29), reused 37 (delta 25), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (46/46), done.
From github.com:ldco2016/project
   7c36686..8c495a6  master                   -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      fix/task-uuid-assignment -> origin/fix/task-uuid-assignment
Auto-merging mix.lock
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in mix.lock
Auto-merging mix.exs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in mix.exs
Auto-merging lib/project/schema.ex
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/project/schema.ex
Auto-merging lib/project/router.ex
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/project/router.ex
Auto-merging lib/project/resolvers/content.ex
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/project/resolvers/content.ex
Auto-merging lib/project/endpoint.ex
Auto-merging lib/project/context.ex
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/project/context.ex
Auto-merging lib/project/channels/user_socket.ex
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/project/channels/user_socket.ex
Auto-merging lib/project/account/account.ex
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I tried this fix:

```
git pull --rebase
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

but obviously, it did not work.

I then tried:

```
git reset --hard
HEAD is now at eb96cbf Require authentication on all types except auth
➜  project git:(master) git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Install Absinthe with task and user types
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   lib/project/account/account.ex
M   lib/project/account/task.ex
M   lib/project_web/endpoint.ex
M   lib/project_web/router.ex
M   mix.exs
M   mix.lock
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging mix.lock
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in mix.lock
Auto-merging mix.exs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in mix.exs
Auto-merging lib/project_web/schema/content_types.ex
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/project_web/schema/content_types.ex
Auto-merging lib/project_web/schema.ex
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/project_web/schema.ex
Auto-merging lib/project_web/router.ex
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/project_web/router.ex
Auto-merging lib/project_web/resolvers/content.ex
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/project_web/resolvers/content.ex
Auto-merging lib/project_web/endpoint.ex
Auto-merging lib/project/account/account.ex
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/project/account/account.ex
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Install Absinthe with task and user types
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

This looked like it was going to work and then said, no, sorry, you have merge conflicts.

Comment: Please show us what your `git pull` actually looked like.  If you really did no work to your branch, then pulling should have resulted in a no-conflict fast forward.

Comment: @ManelPNavarro, I guess I could just trash the current master since I never worked on it and just clone it again. I was hoping there was a more streamlined approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never worked on it, why don't you just clone the project from the origin and then create a new branch?

Another option would be, assuming that you are in master:

```
git pull -f origin master
git checkout -b 'yourNewBranch'
```

Comment: So the above does not solve my problem because of that same message I documented in the OP when I tried doing a `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: Well, the "-f" flag should overwrite the changes, avoiding conflicts. Anyway, if you haven't done any changes, why don't you just delete your local repo and then clone from origin?